# optimize mysql query with huge data using indexing

Tags: mysql

every minute the table size is increasing with 3 columns TimeInsert(timestamp), errorMsg (varchar 50) as 'Success' , 'Failure' and amount (int) . When i run the below query to generate reports of last 3 days , the below query takes a lot of time , how can i make it run fast , using multi column indexes , shall i use indexing for the 2 columns , timeinsert and errorMsg ? the table is myisam

```
select sum(amount) from sdpcallbackairtel where  TimeInsert >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY and errorMsg ='Success' and hour(timeinsert)=16 ;



CREATE TABLE tablename (
`Id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`errorMsg` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`amount` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`TimeInsert` datetime DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: you could partition the data, run separate queries (historical and current) and combine as necessary.

Comment: not allowed to use this . indexing is the only option.

Comment: one could have a covering index. But is it wise to mess with a table just for the purposes of one query? Not for us to say

Comment: **a.** What indexes exist (suggest you provide the current DDL for the table) , and, **b.** provide the explain plan. Plus you should avoid using functions on the data

Comment: CREATE TABLE tablename (
  `Id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `errorMsg` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TimeInsert` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1